# Dataframe set_index not setting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and am trying to set the index to the column 'Timestamp'. Currently the index is just a row number. An example of Timestamp's format is: **2015-09-03 16:35:00**

I've tried to set the index:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp')
```

I don't get an error, but when I print the dataframe, the index is still the row number. How can I use Timestamp as the index?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to either specify `inplace=True`, or assign the result to a variable. Try:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Basically, there are two things that you might want to do when you set the index. One is `new_df = old_df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=False)`. I.e. You want a new DataFrame that has the new index, but still want a copy of the original DataFrame. The other is `df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)`. Which is for when you want to modify the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer:
Remember that you might need to set your timestamp into a datetime!

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataFile)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True, drop=True)
df.info()
```

References:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-set_index/
[how set column as date index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610983/how-set-column-as-date-index)