# Given a DatetimeIndex and a collection of datetime-aware records, how to create a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pre-defined DatetimeIndex and a list of tuples of this kind: (datetime, float, float, float). I need to create a Pandas DataFrame and populate it with the data from the list. Needless to say, the first element of each record (a tuple) defines its supposed position in the resulting DataFrame and not a value of a column, there are to be just 3 float columns in the resulting DataFrame. The records that don't have a matching element in the DatetimeIndex should be discarded (and I don't mind an error to be risen on such an occasion).

Given the list of the tuples itself `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` treats every element of a tuple as a value of a column (and raises an error if I don't include the datetime column in the columns list).

Given a dictionary defined as `{r[0]: (r[1], r[2], r[3]) for r in rs}` (where `rs` is the source list of the tuples) `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` returns a DataFrame where every value in every field of every column is NaN. I've also tried using lists instead of tuples (`{r[0]: [r[1], r[2], r[3]] for r in rs}`) but the result was the same. I've double-checked - the values in the source tuples are pretty much defined floats and there are no NaNs or Nones. Setting `coerce_float` doesn't change anything.

UPDATE: I've also tried using a dictionary of dictionaries to specify column names according to the columns list (`{r[0]: {'A': r[1], 'B': r[2], 'C': r[3]} for r in rs}`) and the result is the same - all NaNs.

UPDATE: Here goes an example:

```
dts = [
    datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc),
    datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc),
    datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc)
]

dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(dts, tz=timezone.utc)

rs = [
    (datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc), 0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
    (datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc), 0.4, 0.5, 0.6),
    (datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc), 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
]

# ...

dtf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rs, index=dti, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], coerce_float=True)

print(dtf)
```

should result in

```
                           A    B    C  
2008-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  0.1  0.2  0.3
2008-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  0.3  0.5  0.6
2008-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

But it actually results in `AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns` if ran this way. What should I write in place of `# ...`? Or, perhaps, what should I use instead of `from_records` to achieve the desired result given the inputs?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston Ok, give me some minutes...

Comment: @ScottBoston Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your given datetime index is named `dti`, just create the dataframe with your list of tuples, set the index to the first datetime column, then reindex to `dti`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rs, columns=['datetime', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df.set_index('datetime').reindex(dti)
              A    B    C
2018-01-01  0.1  0.2  0.3
2018-01-02  0.3  0.5  0.6
2018-01-03  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

Comment: I've missed a detail I probably should have noticed before accepting the answer. The result does actually not print this way: it adds a numeric index column  to the very left and the datetime column is still printed with its name above it. Does this mean the Dateframe has both a numeric and a datetime index or does this mean `set_index` doesn't work?

Comment: Let's say you assign the result above to `df2`, then try to see if the index has a name via `df2.index.name`.  Also, have a look at a few sample values to ensure they match with your expectation via `df2.index[:2]`.  You can remove the name of the index via `df2.index.name = None`. Perhaps you can print a sample of the result via `print(df2.head())`?

Comment: I've figured out that my mistake was excepting the operation to affect the dataframe while it actually returns a new (correct) dataframe instead. There is an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196399/274627 that suggests using `df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True, drop=True)` to apply the change in-place. Should I do it this way to save memory (the dataframe can be really huge in the real life)? What are, if any, the pros and cons?

Comment: I wouldn't use `inplace=True`.  It is often easier and cleaner to just reassign if you no longer need the old data, i.e. `df = df.set_index('datetime').reindex(dti)`.  Also, you can delete `rs` after you've used it to create the dataframe via `del rs`. Also, `drop=True` is the default behavior, so you don't need it.

Comment: BTW can it also make sense to assign the result of set_index() to a new variable and del the original dataframe, then assign the result of reindex() to a new variable and del the result of set_index()? Is this going to help save memory if the dataframe is huge and the unmodified versions are not needed? Does the actual dataframe content get copied in memory on set_index() and on reindex() or maybe it doesn't and then there is no value in unnecessary intermediate variables and dels?

Comment: I don't see any benefits of that approach. If the dataframe is too large to work with it in memory, you may want to consider Dask.  https://dask.org/

Answer (score 1):

The dict comprehension you gave would presumably give you columns named by Datetimes, not rows indexed by Datetimes. Leaving that aside, if you can create a DataFrame with 4 columns, you should just be able to use [DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the Datetime column to be the index, and [DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to index by your given `DatetimeIndex`.

You can also create the DataFrame first, and populate the columns in a loop. The [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) indexer will throw a `KeyError` if the datetime value isn't a key in the index, in which case you can just try the next tuple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=my_datetime_index, columns=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
for r in rs:
    try:
        df.loc[r[0]] = r[1:]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```