# Cant create index with dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use dataframe columns to create an index.

```
#columns in file [<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>]
df = pd.read_csv('DSKY_210101_211106.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[2, 3])
#projection
project = df[['<DATE>', '<TIME>', '<HIGH>']]
project.set_index(['<DATE>','<TIME>'])
print(project)
```

But the index still the same. Why didn't columns become index ?

[image]

Comment: set_index by default creates a new df object, if you want it to change the existing one set `inplace=true` you can see this in the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html `inplacebool, default False
If True, modifies the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object).`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe set\_index not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196337/dataframe-set-index-not-setting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is not in-place, i.e., it creates a *new* dataframe and modifies that. You need to reassign to `project`:

```
project = project.set_index(['<DATE>','<TIME>'])
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. There's no need to answer a question that has been already asked and answered elsewhere. Please first look for duplicates before answering questions, and vote to close as duplicate when appropriate, thanks!

Comment: Oh really? Ok, thank you for find it. I didn't know that there was. I'll save it.  :)

Comment: (In other words, there are many many duplicates in the pandas tag)

Comment: I understand that, but it's often not very easy for me to find duplicates. Often I don't even know they exist :D

Comment: Fair enough! My rule of thumb: if it's a basic pandas question, it's been asked (probably many times) already on this site :D

Comment: That's a good one. I'm collecting a list of duplicates for this very purpose, and I'll make sure to check for previously-asked questions when it's a simple one.

Comment: [Jezrael's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) has a convenient list haha

Comment: Yes actually, it really does. And sure enough, `reset_index dupe` is at the very bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@user17242583's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70278500/17242583) [`pd.Dataframe.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is not inplace unless specified in its arguments:

```py
#columns in file [<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>]
df = pd.read_csv('DSKY_210101_211106.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[2, 3])
#projection
project = df[['<DATE>', '<TIME>', '<HIGH>']]
project.set_index(['<DATE>','<TIME>'], inplace=True)
print(project)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the set_index with inplace= True

Comment: This adds nothing but noise to the thread, which is already a duplicate. Please don't do that.

Comment: This does not add anything to the thread