# set index to Date column residing in level 3 multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

I want to simply set the index to be the Date column which you see as first column. 
The dataframe comes from an api where i save the data into csv:

```
data.to_csv('stocks.csv', header=True ,sep=',',mode='a')
data = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv',header=[0,1,2])
data
```

Preferably i would also like to get rid of the "Unnamed:.." labels you see in the picture.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how set column as date index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610983/how-set-column-as-date-index)

Comment: I tried to swap level 0 with 2, hence making the Date on top. Then applied the simple set_index() as so:

data.columns=data.columns.swaplevel(2,0)
data = data.set_index('Date')

Then I thought i could swap back 2 with 0 and retain the index, but I just was brought back to beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying header=[0,1] ,index_col=0 in the read_csv function and after convert dataframe to numeric since the datatype got distorted but not necessary always i believe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv', header=[0,1] ,index_col=0)
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# eventually:
data = data.dropna()
```

In this fashion I get exactly what I want, namely write e.g.

```
data['AGN.AS']['High']
```

and get the high values for a specific stock.